# Android, RXJava, search using debounce

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm using `debounce()` for handling user searching and dealing with it's pause on typing (searches 1 second after the last char):

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
            .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(new Action1<CharSequence>() {
                @Override
                public void call(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    presenter.loadUsers(charSequence.toString());
                }
            });
```

so if user delete all chars, it waits 1 second and then loads the list, how can I handle it and load the list instantly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case just `debounce` operator with different parameters is needed:

[`public final <U> Observable<T> debounce(Func1<? super T, ? extends Observable<U>> debounceSelector)`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/Observable.java#L5341)

Using it you can filter, which events can be delayed or not:

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)  
    .debounce(new Func1<CharSequence, Observable<CharSequence>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<CharSequence> call(CharSequence charSequence) {
            if (charSequence.length() == 0) {
                return Observable.empty();
            } else {
                return Observable.<CharSequence>empty().delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        }
    })
    .subscribe(new Action1<CharSequence>() {
        @Override
        public void call(CharSequence charSequence) {
            Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), new Date().toGMTString() + " " + charSequence.length() + " :" + charSequence);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You might want to use `Observable.empty()` instead of `Observable.just(charSequence)` in the debounce function. It should be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest form just [merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) the debounced observable with a manual *trigger* like so:

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
        .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .mergeWith(Observable.just("")) // manually tigger onNext with empty search
        .subscribe(new Action1<CharSequence>() {
            @Override
            public void call(CharSequence charSequence) {
                presenter.loadUsers(charSequence.toString());
            }
        });
```